# button in listView

Tags: android, listview

I have Button and TextView in my ListView , and I would add listener on button but I can't do it.

Actually I have in my adapter :

[code]

```
        imgClassement.setImageResource(drawable);
        imgClassement.setTag(mail);
        imgClassement.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

         @Override
         public void onClick(View view){

          //I would like display an alerts in my activity

         }


        });
```

[/code]

The OnClick works but, I would like to display alerts on my activity and I can't do it :/ I don't know how to lie my activity and my adapter

Comment: Whats exactly the problem? Can't do it isn't really a problem description.

And by Alert do you mean AlertDialog?

Answer (score 0):

By using the ClickableListAdapter we can give action to button in listview for each list item.This code while help you for button functionality in list.
    public class Play
    {
    int id;
    String name;
    }

```
ArrayList<Play> playlistname=new ArrayList<Play>();

Listview playlist;
MyClickableListAdapter list= new MyClickableListAdapter(this,R.layout.editlist, playlistname);
playlist.setAdapter(list);

//xml
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="45dip"
           android:orientation="horizontal" 
          >
<Button android:paddingLeft="5dip" android:id="@+id/playlisticon"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:paddingRight="5sp" />             
<TextView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/playlistname"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
   android:padding="10dp" android:textStyle="bold"
   android:textSize="12px" android:layout_weight="1">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>     

static class MyViewHolder extends "packagename of your app".ClickableListAdapter.ViewHolder 
{ 
     TextView text; 
         ImageView icon;
         public MyViewHolder(TextView id,ImageView i) 
         {  
        text = id;  
        icon = i;
         } 
 }

  //MyClickableListAdapter to perform on click functionality on ListView
 public class MyClickableListAdapter extends ClickableListAdapter 
 {

    public MyClickableListAdapter(Context context, int viewid,List<Play> objects)
    {  

        super(context, viewid, objects); 
    } 
    protected void bindHolder(ViewHolder holder)
         { 
        MyViewHolder mvh = (MyViewHolder) holder;  
        Play item = (Play)mvh.data;  

            mvh.icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //this is button
            mvh.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel_button);  
            mvh.text.setText(item.name);//this textview
      } 
    @Override  
    protected ViewHolder createHolder(View v) 
    {
        TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.playlistname); 
        ImageView  icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.playlisticon);
        ViewHolder mvh = new MyViewHolder(text,icon);   

        icon.setOnClickListener(new ClickableListAdapter.OnClickListener(mvh) 
        {  
            public void onClick(View v, ViewHolder viewHolder)
            {  
                 // we toggle the enabled state and also switch the icon  

                MyViewHolder mvh = (MyViewHolder) viewHolder;  
                final Play item = (Play) mvh.data;  
                //check the id to delete the PlayList from second List 
                //here u can write the function that has to work while we 
                                      click on each button in list      
                } 
        });   
                return mvh; // finally, we return our new holder  

 }

   //this class for ClickableListAdapter  used for clicking the any item in the list.....
   public abstract class ClickableListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
   {
String type;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<?> mDataObjects;
private int mViewId;

public static class ViewHolder
{
public Object data;
}

public static abstract class OnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
private ViewHolder mViewHolder;

public  OnClickListener(ViewHolder holder)
{
    mViewHolder=holder;
}
public void onClick(View v)
{
    onClick(v,mViewHolder);
}
 public abstract void onClick(View v, ViewHolder viewHolder);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
};

public ClickableListAdapter(Context context, int viewid,
        List< "applicationpackagename".Play> objects) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);  
         mDataObjects = objects;  
         mViewId = viewid;  
         type="Rowcontain";

        if (objects == null) 
        {  
            mDataObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();  
        }  
}
public ClickableListAdapter(Context context, int viewid,
        List<  "applicationpackagename".Play> objects, int x) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);  
         mDataObjects = objects;  
         mViewId = viewid;  
         type="Rowdata";
        if (objects == null)
        {  
            mDataObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();  
        }  
}



@Override
public int getCount()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mDataObjects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return  mDataObjects.get(position); 
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(view==null)
    {
          view = mInflater.inflate(mViewId, null);  
          // call the user's implementation  
          holder = createHolder(view);  
          // we set the holder as tag  
          view.setTag(holder);  

    } 
    else
    {  
         // get holder back...much faster than inflate  
         holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();  
    }  

    // we must update the object's reference  
    holder.data = getItem(position);  
    // call the user's implementation  
    bindHolder(holder);  
    return view;  
}  
protected abstract ViewHolder createHolder(View v);  
protected abstract void bindHolder(ViewHolder h);  
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

In fact , when user click on button, I would display a list above the first one. So I think about AlertsDialog to do that. And if user click on the entire row, I display another activity.

But like the OnClick is on the Adapter, I couldn't retrieve position of the selected item of the list on the activity.

Actually the click on the entire row works, but not the click on the button which is on the row.

Comment: Please don't post more details to a problem as an answer. Just edit your question

Comment: sorry, I didn't pay attention that we can just add a comment.